# SMART Input Program

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I have a 3ware 9650se card with 4 SATA drives attached to it. I've been trying to figure out how to convert the SMART data I can get from the web interface into something usable, but I haven't found a program that will just take what I give it and tell me what it means. Sure I could try and decipher it myself, but I'd rather not do that. So does anyone know of a program (could be online) where I can feed it the SMART data and it tells me what it means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be fairly simple to compare the output you have with the manufacturer's documentation. See the detailed description of each SMART variable below:

- [Fujitsu](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki/AttributesFujitsu)
- [IBM / Hitachi](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki/AttributesIBM)
- [Maxtor](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki/AttributesMaxtor)
- [Seagate](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki/AttributesSeagate)
- [Western Digital](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki/AttributesWestern-Digital)

See also the [3ware SMART documentation](http://www.3ware.com/KB/article.aspx?id=10080).

Answer (score 1):

You could let some software talk to the drives rather than using after-the-fact parsing. [Smartmontools](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki) lists at least partial support for 3ware controllers

Comment: Yeah, you'd think that would be the easy way, but I can get Smartmontools to work, which is why I asked the question.. :)  Guess I should have mentioned that. I don't want to install HDTune or anything like that on the server, since its a server...